# Help identifying orphaned or redundant system apps

Tags: gnome, 20.04, cinnamon, installed-programs

Trying to streamline my existing Ubuntu Studio Cinnamon 20.04 experience. I know I could just start over rather than strive to clean things up from various distros and apps over time, but I would love to keep my current everything as is, except what can go. Really don't care about software dependencies that cost me an app here or there while trying to clean things up.

Looking at installed apps, maybe a system file or add-on can safely go? Hoping to identify what is redundant or not needed here and recommended removal. Per post reqs, also listing them here:

GNOME 3.26 runtime

GNOME 3.28 runtime

gnome-3-34-1804

GTK2 Common Themes

GTK Common Themes

kde-frameworks-5-core18

kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18

core

Core 18

core20

I know I need to keep core and Core20, of course. But lost on the rest though I know some apps need them. Presuming I only had Ubuntu Studio Cinnamon installed and no apps added, would be great to know what must stay and what can go. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't sound like a stock Ubuntu Studio installation. What is it?

Comment: Well, it's probably a messy hybrid of stuff over the years beyond simple upgrades as I may have tried experimenting with different Ubuntu offerings. I'm glad it doesn't look normal, because that's my concern, but i cannot offer more on what it is apart from what you see here. Seem to have ended up with this.

Comment: That's what I thought. Best to backup your important data, and do a fresh install of Studio, then restore your data.

Comment: Sadly, I agree. Will only make it better this next time around. Thanks for the affirmation.

Comment: So did a fresh install. Doesn't look much different: 
GNOME 3.28 runtime
gnome-3-34-1804
GTK2 Common Themes
GTK Common Themes
kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18
core
Core 18
core20

Comment: At least you can take comfort that any leftovers are gone, and you should have nice solid running system :-)

Comment: Yes. Feels fresh and new. Only issue, unrelated to topic, is it did a UEFI install and my little 32GB Legacy drive on the board is no longer available cuz of limited BIOS config options to boot. Small loss. Overall made the right decision. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working good for you. Is that 32G drive an Optane drive?

Comment: Thanks. It's 32GB eMMC storage on the motherboard. Was always available on Legacy boot from BIOS but this Ubuntu 20.04 install ended up being UEFI. Fortunately, the BIOS is comfy with that, but the 32GB is gone. If I insist on Legacy boot from BIOS then I end up in a GRUB error state. That does show the 32GB but I don't like having to work through the error state. I know this discussion is out there. Just noting what happened with the reinstall. Again, it was definitely the right thing to do. Much more control.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Glad that you're happy with your "new" setup.